# Vim Error E20 'Mark not set' when running BuffWrite Command

Tags: vim, autocommand

I set up an auto run script in my vimrc to condense any block of 3 or more empty newlines down to 3 newlines. I set a mark so after the script executes, I retain my cursor position but I'm getting an E20 **Mark not set** error when the cursor is within an area that is being removed.

How can I fix this issue/silence the error when this happens?

`" .vimrc file: 
autocmd BufWrite * mark ' | silent! %s/\n\{3,}/\r\r\r/e | norm''`

Comment: You typically don't need `silent!` if you are using the `e` flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your marks with `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`.

```
autocmd BufWrite * let w:winview = winsaveview() | ... | if exists('w:winview') | call winrestview(w:winview) | endif
```

Comment: This worked! Used `autocmd BufWrite * let w:winview = winsaveview() | %s/\n\{3,}/\r\r\r/e | if exists('w:winview') | call winrestview(w:winview) | endif`

Answer (score 0):

Also silence the normal command:

```
autocmd BufWrite * mark ' | silent! %s/\n\{3,}/\r\r\r/e | silent! exe "norm! ''"
```